# crash in boost::split algorithm (can not access memory)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am getting following crash in boost algorithm

stack trace is :

```
#0  0x0000000000451432 in boost::algorithm::predicate_facade<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>
>::predicate_facade (
    this=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff3feff8>) at /med/build/boost/boost_1_43_0/boost/algorithm/string/predicate_facade.hpp:36
#1  0x0000000000451454 in boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>::is_any_ofF (this=0x7fffff3ff090, Other=...)
    at /med/build/boost/boost_1_43_0/boost/algorithm/string/detail/classification.hpp:107
#2  0x0000000000452517 in boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>
>::operator()<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> > (
    this=0x7ffe5169a6b0, Begin=..., End=...) at /med/build/boost/boost_1_43_0/boost/algorithm/string/detail/finder.hpp:570
#3  0x0000000000453f29 in boost::detail::function::function_obj_invoker2<boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>
>, boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >::invoke (
    function_obj_ptr=..., a0=..., a1=...) at /med/build/boost/boost_1_43_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:132
#4  0x0000000000453a3a in boost::function2<boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >::operator() (this=0x7fffff3ff450, a0=..., a1=...) at /med/build/boost/boost_1_43_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1013
#5  0x0000000000453080 in boost::algorithm::detail::find_iterator_base<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >::do_find (this=0x7fffff3ff450, Begin=..., End=...)
    at /med/build/boost/boost_1_43_0/boost/algorithm/string/detail/find_iterator.hpp:63
#6  0x00000000004527fe in boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >::increment (this=0x7fffff3ff450)
    at /med/build/boost/boost_1_43_0/boost/algorithm/string/find_iterator.hpp:297
#7  0x0000000000454f12 in boost::iterator_core_access::increment<boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> > > (f=...)
    at /med/build/boost/boost_1_43_0/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:522
#8  0x0000000000454e2c in boost::iterator_facade<boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>
> const, boost::forward_traversal_tag, boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>
> const&, long>::operator++ (
    this=0x7fffff3ff450) at /med/build/boost/boost_1_43_0/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:664
#9  0x00000000004548a6 in boost::iterator_adaptor<boost::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::string,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, std::string, boost::use_default, std::string, boost::use_default>::increment (this=0x7fffff3ff450)
    at /med/build/boost/boost_1_43_0/boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp:339
#10 0x0000000000454318 in boost::iterator_core_access::increment<boost::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::string,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default> > (f=...)
    at /med/build/boost/boost_1_43_0/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:522
#11 0x0000000000453bda in boost::iterator_facade<boost::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::string,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>, std::string, boost::forward_traversal_tag, std::string, long>::operator++ (this=0x7fffff3ff450) at /med/build/boost/boost_1_43_0/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:664
#12 0x000000000045326d in std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>
>::_M_range_initialize<boost::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::string,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default> > (this=0x7fffff3ff6a0, __first=..., __last=...)
    at /med/build/gcc/gcc-4.7.2/linux64/gcc-4.7.2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_vector.h:1157
#13 0x0000000000452aa8 in std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>
>::_M_initialize_dispatch<boost::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::string,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default> > (this=0x7fffff3ff6a0, __first=..., __last=...)
    at /med/build/gcc/gcc-4.7.2/linux64/gcc-4.7.2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_vector.h:1148
#14 0x0000000000452206 in std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>
>::vector<boost::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::string,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string> >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default> > (
    this=0x7fffff3ff6a0, __first=..., __last=..., __a=...)
    at /med/build/gcc/gcc-4.7.2/linux64/gcc-4.7.2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_vector.h:393
#15 0x0000000000451a87 in boost::algorithm::iter_split<std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >, std::string, boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>
> > (Result=..., Input=..., Finder=...) at /med/build/boost/boost_1_43_0/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:178
```

function used as foloows in the code :

```
boost::split(signals, name, boost::is_any_of("."), boost::token_compress_on); 
template<typename Derived>
struct predicate_facade {};
```

In above code, i am getting can not access memory error in gdb for this pointer :

```
(gdb) p this Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff3feff8
```

But it worked fine in small code (tried on ideone):
https://www.ideone.com/jnB037
Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take your broken version and minimize it until it matches with your small code. Make sure you always use same inputs. During this process, you will find the error.

Comment: Can't help you without a minimal reproducible example